# Why is this code causing a segmentation fault?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>


void main()
{
FILE  *fp,*fp1;
char c;
fp=fopen("test.txt","r");
fp1=fopen("test1.txt","w");
c=getc(fp);
while(c!=EOF)
{
    if (c=="")
    {
        c=getc(fp);
        continue;
    }
    else 
        fprintf(fp1,"%s",c);
    c=getc(fp);
}
fclose(fp);
fclose(fp1);

}
```

Comment: You already have answers to the specific question but in general, do you have a debugger?  That's the best way to find out the at least immediate cause of any particular segmentation fault.

Comment: You should get into the habit of good variable names like `file1` & `file2` rather than `fp` & `fp1`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because character is not a string.

Try fputc.

BTW: The c should be int, otherwise you won't be able to detect EOF. EOF > 255.

Comment: Nitpick: EOF is usually (but doesn't have to be) less than 0.

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of things wrong with the code that might cause problems.

`fp` and `fp1` should be checked against `NULL` after being assigned the result of `fopen` to check for file open failures.

The type of `c` should be `int` so that you can properly distinguish `EOF` from a valid character read correctly.

`c == ""` attempts to compare character value with the address of a literal zero-length string.

`fprintf(fp1,"%s",c)` interprets that character value c as the address of a constant string and attempts to follow this address to print a string. This is the most likely error to cause a segmentation fault.

---

Less important style issues.

The return value of `main` should be an `int`. It's portably correct even if many implementations do allow `void main(void)`.

As the body of your `if` clause matches what would happen if the loop ran to the end and is followed by a `continue`, it would be probably be clearer to remove this clause and apply an if statement with the opposite of what you think `c==""` should become, to what is currently the `else` statement.

Answer (score 5):

`c==""` also won't work like you think it does.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the fprintf("%s") of the variable c. c is not a string, it's a single character. Replace that line with

```
fprintf(fp1,"%c",c);
```

And it will work. There are better ways to actually copy the contents of one file to another.

Comment: Well the best way would be "cp". But I gather this is an exercise or you're trying to do something more interesting, like filter the contents while copying.

The biggest problem with the approach above is reading a character at a time is very slow. At a minimum you want to read and write the files a chunk at a time via read()/write() or fread()/fwrite() or the like with a block size of about 16k.

Comment: yeah i am stripping all the white spaces .. developing a lexer. so as of now its not working with that method

Answer (score 0):

The code gives segmentation fault due to illegal memory access, fprintf looks for null character to terminate and in this process accesses invalid memory location.
 Also file pointers must be checked for null and code should exit gracefully if any of them is null otherwise it will also cause a segfault.